# HTML5 audio conversion using NodeJS on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, ffmpeg, html5-audio, transcoding

I have a HTML5 app that allows users to upload and play their audio files. The server is Node running on Heroku.

To allow cross-browser audio play, what I understand is that I have to at least maintain two formats of each audio file, let's say .mp3 and .ogg. So, I need to transcode the files automatically on the server side.

The problem is that Heroku does not run ffmpeg. I found this project that creates a custom buildpack for heroku that supports ffmpeg but it seems to be for Rails apps: https://github.com/dzello/ffmpeg-heroku.

I was thinking to run an external server for transcoding, which my nodejs app sends the file to, it does the transcoding, and reuploads the new file on my nodejs server. But I don't know how to set up such a server, and whether there is already a ready solution which does this kind of work?

So, here are my questions:

```
1- Is there a solution to run ffmpeg on heroku+nodejs?

2- How can I set up a transcoding server that communicates with my nodejs+heroku server?
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to run it on heroku? Just setup some virtual server, for example on [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/?refcode=25ec1ed21a93)

And use a linux server to setup node. It's pretty easy and will run every package needed. It already has droplet with preconfigured node.js+mongodb stack